# How to disable Google Analytics for Firebase web hosting project

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

Google Analytics was enabled when Firebase hosting project was first setup but now I don't want it anymore.
Is there a way to remove Google Analytics from Firebase Hosting site so that google tag script is no longer dynamically added to the site.

[image]

[image]